# Suggest a function $f(n)$ such that $\log{n}\times \log^{*}{n} > f(n) > c \times \log{n}$

Tags: functions, computational-complexity

- I want to find a function $f(n)$ where
  $$f(n) > c \times \log{n}, \quad c\text{ is arbitrary constant}$$
  ,and there is no function $f'(n)$ where 
  $$f(n)>f'(n)>c \times \log{n}$$
- I can set $f(n) = \log{n}\times \log^{*}{n}$, which is greater than $c \times \log{n}$. But I think that maybe there is a function $f'(n)$ which is less than $f(n)$.

> Can you suggest a function $f(n)$ such that $\log{n}\times \log^{*}{n} > f(n) > c \times \log{n}?$

Comment: What does the $*$ in $\log^*$ mean?

Comment: Like $\lg n \times \sqrt{\lg^* n}$?

Comment: if $\log^{(2)} n:=\log \log n$, then $\log^* n \leq 2$, i.e. number of times you need to take $\log$ to get to $1$ or $2$

Comment: I suppose there are uncountable many $O$ classes in between